# Do we really need to copy this.myVolatile locally to do the synchronization double if pattern in Java 8?

Tags: java, synchronization, volatile

Do we get any benefit to change existing code from:

```
class MyClass {
    volatile Object myVariable;
    Object myMethod() {
        if (myVariable == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (myVariable == null) {
                    myVariable = this.getNewValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return myVariable;
    }
}
```

to

```
class MyClass {
    volatile Object myVariable;
    Object myMethod() {
        Object tmp = this.myVariable;
        if (tmp == null) {
            synchronized(this) {
                tmp = this.myVariable;
                if (tmp == null) {
                    this.myVariable = tmp = this.getNewValue();
                }
            }   
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I don't see the point of copying this.myVariable locally before using it, and I don't think it's a good practice to use "this." for every class variable.

Comment: `void Object myMethod()` - am I seeing 2 return types or do I need a coffee?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java: *Note the local variable "localRef", which seems unnecessary. The effect of this is that in cases where helper is already initialized (i.e., most of the time), the volatile field is only accessed once (due to "return localRef;" instead of "return helper;")*

Comment: @Kartik: you might have caught me between edits. Check it now.

Comment: @Kartik: Yes, you're right, it doesn't make sense. I have no idea what OP means. Feel free to edit if you can make it sensible.

Comment: @JamesKPolk we shouldn't edit it because it'll change the whole code - see how something is returned from `if` block but returns nothing from outside it. The OP should make the code compile first.

Comment: As @Kartik says *no rv if `tmp != null`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying to a local variable is more efficient and more correct.

More Efficient: Assume that in the common case, `myVariable` is non-null.  In the first version, you do *two* reads of `myVariable`, once to check for null and once to return the value.  In the second version, you do one read of `myVariable` and two reads of `tmp` (local variable access, which is trivial).  The whole point of using volatile is the strong memory guarantees, and those guarantees mean that two reads is a non-trivial performance hit over just one read.

More Correct: Assume that `myVariable` is some sort of "cache" which periodically needs to be refreshed.  I.e. there is a background thread which periodically sets `myVariable` to `null` so that it will be reloaded on the next read.  In the first version, you do *two* separate reads of `myVariable`.  The first read could return non-`null`, then the "cache refresh" logic runs and sets `myVariable` to `null`.  The second read (to return the value) then returns `null`!  In the second version, `tmp` is *always* the value you tested for `null` (assuming that `getNewValue()` never returns `null` of course).

Note that using "this." is a stylistic choice in this code and has no bearing on the correctness or performance issues.

This is largely just expanding on what is stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java .

Comment: I think it is "potentially more correct" rather than "more correct". This idiom is used in many cases where it is known that `myVariable` never gets set back to null.

Comment: @ruakh - fair, i'm stretching the point.  but, i've seen similar logic where a volatile variable is tested for some state and then the volatile variable is used again in the return statement, opening a hole where the test could no longer hold true.  it's _always_ good practice to copy a volatile variable to a local variable while working with it (regardless of the programmers current beliefs of how it might be manipulated).